# Why functions FORMAT and FORMATNUMBER return string? how can i get a number?

Tags: vba

How can I change the format of a number, and not change the number into a string. I need to represent the thousand point in the table of a legend. I need to format the source, and I can just do this with the FORMAT and NUMBERFORMAT. the return though strings, that means, I can not generate the graph.

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A number does not have a format. You can write a number using a given format, but then the result is a written text, i.e. a string. Probably you want to use a formatted string for the legend and the number for your graph.

Comment: Don't _format_ the number because it will be _converted_ to a string (as wkl said a number itself has not formatting, formatting is a representation thing; You can write 2 or 10b but it's the same _number_). You must apply formatting to the cell, not to its content (assuming you're using Excel)

Comment: What are you using to display your chart?

Comment: i am showing the graph in powerpoint. That's exactly the point. I want to format the table cells from the legend, and in the graphs the numbers should be numbers, otherwise you can't represent anything. I think it's impossible in excel to do that. neither with excel nor with macros it can be achieved :(

Comment: So basically you want to show a chart in powerpoint but define the format of the numbers on the chart. You don't need to format that in the source (in excel). You just build the chart as normal and define formatting in the chart. It's all in the graph generation / rendering, _not_ in the source data.